# Next Label using tab on keyboard (Bootstrap)

Tags: php, html, bootstrap-4

I'm a beginner at Bootstrap. When I press Tab, I want to select the next tab.

Click loan_form.php and then the cursor is automatically in **Loan Name**. After you complete it and press tab on the keyboard, the cursor will move to the **Department** label instead of the **Device code** label:

[image: 2-column form]

```
<div class="row">                        
<div class="col-md-6 mb-3">
  <label>* Loan Name</label>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" name="loan_name" id="loan_name" placeholder="Full Name" required>
</div>

<div class="col-md-6 mb-3">
  <label>Device Code</label>
  <select name="device_code" class="form-control" id="device_code" data-validetta="required" ></select>
</div>
</div>
<br />

<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-6 mb-3">
  <label>* Department</label>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" name="dept" id="dept" placeholder="Department" required></div>

<div class="col-md-6 mb-3">
  <label>Brand</label>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" name="device_brand" id="device_brand" placeholder="Brand" disabled required>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `tabindex` html tag in all the `input` fields. See reformatted code here:

```
<div class="row">                        
<div class="col-md-6 mb-3">
  <label>* Loan Name</label>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" name="loan_name" id="loan_name" placeholder="Full Name" required tabindex="1">
</div>

<div class="col-md-6 mb-3">
  <label>Device Code</label>
  <select name="device_code" class="form-control" id="device_code" data-validetta="required" tabindex="2"></select>
</div>
</div>
<br />

<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-6 mb-3">
  <label>* Department</label>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" name="dept" id="dept" placeholder="Department" required tabindex="3"></div>

<div class="col-md-6 mb-3">
  <label>Brand</label>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" name="device_brand" id="device_brand" placeholder="Brand" disabled required tabindex="4">
</div>
```